# Tags "jsr310" and "java-time"

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

Now that Java 8 has been released with the [`java.time`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) package, which is the recommended way of working with date and time in Java 8, should some cleanup be done on questions with the [jsr310](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsr310) tag?   [JSR-310](http://www.threeten.org/) was the specification request that eventually became `java.time`.

Reviewing through the questions, they seem to break down into the following categories:

1. Questions tagged [jsr310](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsr310) that are related to the [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
2. Questions tagged [jsr310](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsr310) that are related to JSR310 as [`javax.time`](http://threeten.sourceforge.net/apidocs/javax/time/package-summary.html), before `java.time` was finalized.
3. Questions tagged [jsr310](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsr310) that are about `java.time` in Java 8.
4. Questions tagged [java-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-time) that are about `java.time` in Java 8.
5. Questions tagged [java-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-time) that are just about time issues in Java in general, and not related to `java.time` in Java 8.

There is currently no tag wiki for [java-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-time).  One should probably be created, but first I'd like opinions on whether it's the appropriate tag for `java.time` questions or not.  If so, then questions in category 5 above should probably be re-tagged.

Then, should [jsr310](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsr310) become a synonym for [java-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-time)?  Or should there be some re-tagging to move questions in category 2 and 3?

Should category 1 be left alone?  Or perhaps re-tagged as [jsr310-backport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsr310-backport)?  Or since they may be valid questions for `java.time` also, should they just all be merged to [java-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-time)?

Comment: Is there a decision here? Can it be actioned?

Comment: @JodaStephen Sorry, been falling behind on this.  I'll start going through each post and making the changes as you and Jon suggested.  I agree with you on using 'threeten-backport'.  I'll update this thread with questions about any items that are not obvious how they should be categorized.

Answer (score 4):

For category 1, I would say if they're *explicitly* related to the backport, then [jsr310-backport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsr310-backport) makes sense. Otherwise, [java-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-time) makes sense.

For category 2, if they're `javax.time` related and the interface has changed for `java.time`, then arguably they should just be deleted as they'll potentially do more harm than good. If they're still valid, then [java-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-time)` is better.

For category 3, just retag (or possibly have a tag synonym).

Category 4 is already okay.

Category 5... tricky. I'd probably use two separate tags, [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) and [time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/time).

Answer (score 2):

Category 1 - should be named [threeten-backport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/threeten-backport) (jsr-310-backport is incorrect, as it is explicitly not a jsr-310 implementation).

More broadly, the question is whether [java-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-time) already has a meaning (questions about time in Java, aka category 5) or whether it can be taken to have the desired meaning (category 4). Category 2 and 3 are just historic versions of the true `java.time` API at this point, JSR-310 no longer really exists in my mind.

One way to get more specific is to create tags [java8-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java8-time) and [java-pre8-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-pre8-time) but this gets complex real soon.

Overall, I think my choice is to define [java-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-time) as everything to do with `java.time` in Java 8, and push out general questions about Java 7 and before. [jsr-310](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsr-310) could be left for those questions that are historic (about the process of JSR-310 from 2007 to 2013) but that might get confusing. Perhaps there is a way to "lock" a tag to prevent new questions?