# It's [java.time] to move to [java-time]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

About 100 questions have been tagged with [java.time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java.time) when [java-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-time) has existed for quite a while now and has more than 1000 questions.

The latter is the "official" one as decided in [this other question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266922/829571) and its tag info is much more extensive.

Can they be merged into [java-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-time)?

Comment: The permutation [[tag:java.time]] was not discussed in the previous Q&A. Any subject-matter experts have an opinion on whether [[tag:java.time]] is preferable to [[tag:java-time]]?

Comment: @CodyGray [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) is the package name for all date/time related classes. I guess it's probably more correct. However `java-time` signifies it's about time handling in Java, which should largely be covered by the `java.time` package but technically you might have a question for outside of that. Not sure if it really matters, though - both tags descriptions focus mostly on `java.time`. My preference would be to go with the dash. I'm not sure it makes sense to ask about the package itself rather than time handling.

Comment: @CodyGray I agree with VLAZ and I believe people who are expert on the matter have been using `java-time` for 5 or 6 years without any complaints, so I see no reason to change it now. I have been following the `java-time` tag since the beginning and had never come across the other tag before. It would be interesting to know when `java.time` was created (the first tag edit is from 2018, so that could be the creation date but I'm not sure) - I guess it came a long time after the original one.

Comment: It seems both of you concluded differently than me. I was leaning towards [[tag:java.time]], since that appears to be the clearest, most official name. When it was created really doesn't matter. I can transparently rename a tag, keeping the old name as a synonym. Nothing breaks. But it's not my subject area, so I don't have a strong opinion.

Comment: Not sure if "recent" is the right word. `java.time` was introduced with java SE 8 (March 18, 2014). Perhaps to find which should be used, one could see if there's more use of the **.** (← dot) since 2014. The older time may have also prompted more Questions, since I expect it was more a hazzle before Java 8.

Comment: @CodyGray So if you do your magic and choose the dot version as the main one, and if one creates a new question with the dash tag, it will automatically be renamed with the dot?

Comment: Yes, that's how all synonyms work. Any attempt to use a tag that is a synonym will be renamed automatically to the main tag.

Comment: @CodyGray I don't think I have much preference over the package name or not. I slightly prefer the dash but I think it's pretty clear what the intent is in either case.

Comment: If there's no risk that a new will be created once there's a synonym, then the `-` probably makes more sense, since the **.** (← dot) seems limited to the specific package.

Comment: Agreed, then, @Scratte. There is also a [[tag:java.time.instant]]. Thoughts on that? Is that a reason to go with [[tag:java.time]] for parallelism, or should [[tag:java.time.instant]] also be merged into [[tag:java-time]]?

Comment: @CodyGray java.time.instant relates to a specific class and is therefore more specific - I don't think it should be merged.

Comment: @assylias I'm not sure I agree. It is reasonable to have tags for individual java classes? We also have the class `java.sql.Date`, which I would expect to be covered in "java-time".

Comment: @Scratte I don't know about your question, but I disagree with your comment: java.sql.Date is not part of the java time package and should not be merged.

Comment: @assylias I'm confused now. If you're just interested in a tag for a specific package, then I do not understand why you're opting for java-time, which I would understand as being time handling regardless of package. If we're merging time handling into a tag, then why not include a specific class in there also (I'm referring to `java.time.Instant`)? I went looking into the "java.time.instant" tag and found that most of is isn't isolated to this class, but multiple classes in the `java.time` package anyway.

Comment: About the java.sql.Date class, I've seen Questions about how to convert between that and java.time.LocalDate, which I would assume would also be covered by time handling. But we're in luck, as there is no "java.sql.Date" tag - yet :)

Comment: As I recall, the **Stack Exchange sites have a technical problem with tag names containing a dot** (period, FULL STOP). We have been advised in the past to never use that character in a tag name. The HYPHEN-MINUS is a substitute for the FULL STOP. I do not remember the details of the technical problem.

Comment: I expect that we cannot avoid having both tags java-time and java.tine going forward, and I certainly agree that they should be synonyms.

Comment: @Basil I am not aware of any point where Stack Exchange sites have had problems with periods in tag names. They certainly don't now, and have supported this at least since 2012, probably earlier (that's just the earliest reference I could find). There [was a proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157765) to make the tag picker ignore periods, as it currently does with hyphens, but that's not been implemented best as I can tell. I upvoted it years ago.

Comment: I created the tag java.time.instant because peole were more than once erroneously using the instant tag for questions about the `java.time.Instant` class (I’d be fine with renaming to java-time-instant, but I think we need a specific tag to offer people who want a tag for that class). By now we have tags localdate, localtime, localdatetime and zoneddatetime for those java.time classes (sometimes used a bit broader). We also had tags java.util.date, java.util.calendar (with dots), dateformat, simpledateformat and xmlgregoriancalendar for those old Java classes.

Comment: @CodyGray « Avoid punctuation (which can make it difficult to use the tag in a URL) » from the Help page, [*What are tags, and how should I use them?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) Today i asked: [*Can I use a dot ( period, FULL STOP) character in a tag name?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398814/642706)